# Что такое репликация SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Собственно понятия не имею что есть репликация `SQL` или `SQL` репликация (как правильно?) . Гугл в помощь понятное дело, но может ли кто словами дилетанта привести пример что это?

Вот взять запросы к базе данных это одно, есть импорт экспорт таблиц. Репликация это еще что то? Прошу, объясните, что это теоретически.

Comment: А каким образом вы искали? Первые же ссылки полностью раскрывают всю суть, вам почитать лень? http://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/

Comment: @lampa , я читал это на харбаре, статья хороша. Но иногда нужно, что то очень короткое и емкое. Это как в бух-учете, что такое дебет с кредитом сразу запомнит не каждый, а вот если сказать: Дебет -> нам, Кредит -> Мы, то вникание происходит более быстро.

Comment: а вот [грабли](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_CAP) на которые наступает каждый кто сказал слово репликация. чудес не бывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Репликация (англ. replication)** — механизм синхронизации содержимого нескольких копий объекта (например, содержимого базы данных). Репликация — это процесс, под которым понимается копирование данных из одного источника на другой (или на множество других) и наоборот.
При репликации изменения, сделанные в одной копии объекта, могут быть распространены в другие копии.

Репликация делается автоматически, вам не надо делать вручную эскпорт, потом импорт.

Comment: Вместо тысячи слов блин. Спасибо. Наконец дошло. На моем языке это синхронизация скорее ))

Comment: ну да, можно и так сказать)

Answer (score 2):

Это синхронизация между несколькими серверами, т.е. в теории напримр есть сервер с БД сайта, к которому в минуту обращаются 5000 посетителей и сервак заметно подтормаживает, тогда вам одну и туже БД надо иметь на 2-х серверах чтобы посетителей делить по 2500 на каждый сервер, для того чтобы посетители получали одну и туже инфу с разных серверов их надо синхронизировать, вот собственно такая синхронизация и называется репликацией

Comment: Спасибо, но сорри, 2 акцепта влепить не могу. От @thunder'а уже узнал, что это

Comment: ну как репликацию использовать это уже другой вопрос) относится это, кстати коворя, не только в БД, так же Load-balancing часто используется и для сайтов с точки зрения кода....